Occassional Black Screen on Ubuntu 20.04 on a 7" Touchscreen
I am using a 7" touchscreen with an intel E3950 processor board. I am trying to run a GUI application on 20.04 on this setup.
On 20.04 (with 5.15 kernel) quite frequently the SBC boots into a black screen. The OS boots but doesnt display anything. If i unplug the dsplay power and replug it, it starts working.
On 22.04 (with 6.5 kernel), it works much better, however, once in 20 power cycles it fails to display.

If it was the OS it would not work or would work unlikely to fail just sometimes. Have you investigated the unknown brand tablet if it is a problem there?  Visited their support?

Hi David, the vendor is not very supportive so i'm trying to fix it by myself. From the observations, does it not seem like a driver issue? The same screen has different behaviour with kernel change.

There is nothing about using different kernels and getting different results in your question. Any help you get will only be a s good as the info supplied. Please edit the question and add what kernels you have tried and how it has affected the issue.

Edited. Just for easy understanding of everyone, i have tested two kernel versions. One with Ubuntu 20.04 (5.15 kernel) and another with 22.04 (6.5 kernel). The frequency of black screen outputs is 1 in 20 with 6.5 kernel and 1 in 3 with 5.15 kernel.

Also, I tried checking for proprietary drivers for the display but the driver installer returns no drivers.

There will not be a driver. Drivers are for graphics cards not for displays.

One more piece of information: the display works perfectly with windows. Does that help?
